# How do you find the shipments applied to an order in the Magento SOAP API?

Tags: php, magento, soap

Here is the API Documentation for a Sales Order:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.info.html

Here is the API documentation for a Shipment:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrderShipment/salesOrderShipment.html

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to establish a relationship between them. The order/info endpoint doesn't seem to return a shipment_id of any kind and the order/shipment endpoint doesn't seem to be filterable by order_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible by using a filter on the order's `order_id` value.

Note that `order_id` is different to the order's `increment_id` which is the usual customer facing reference number. Therefore an extra step is required to convert the order's reference into the `order_id`.

I can't give you working PHP code, I'm working in Java, but I can describe the method:

1. Get the order data for your order number (`increment_id`) using `sales_order.info` API call
2. get the `order_id` from the order data
3. Use the `order_id` as a filter in `sales_order_shipment.list`
4. This will give you a list of shipments each with an `increment_id`. This id is the shipment's reference.
5. Use the shipment's `increment_id` in `sales_order_shipment.info` to get more details.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the PHP code to complete @Kevin Sadler answer:

```
/** @var array $filters */
$filters = array(
    array('order_id' => array('eq' => $orderId)) // Entity ID, not Increment ID
);

/** @var array $orderShipments */
$orderShipments = $client->call($session, 'sales_order_shipment.list', $filters);
```